Остановка телеграм бота на аиограм
Всем привет, подскажите в чем может заключаться моя проблема?
Бот написан на aiogram3
Суть в том, что в боте реализована регистрация с помощью машины состояний, зачастую все исправно работает, но сегодня при тестировании столкнулся с такой проблемой:
В момент регистрации на этапе ответа на вопрос бот неожиданно перестал считывать сообщения пользователя, в том числе команду /start. Спустя какое то время он исправно ответил на все отправленные пользователем сообщения. Такое возникает крайне редко, но бывает. Что самое главное-в консоле нет никаких сообщений (все функции реализованы через try-except, но даже с учетом этого консоль остается пустой)
Бот запускается методом старт поллинг

Можно код? Я думаю тут дело не машине состояний если даже старт не работал, а дело в том что у тебя запущен два экземпляра бота в одно время. Странно что консоль об этом не предупредила.
